# How can I add more space between content and contact module

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this page:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

http://i61.tinypic.com/sg0th3.png

See in the picture above that my content override module contact (mobile only)
Picture I made a resolution is a iPhone5.

I want to be a space between the two and I managed to add unfortunately

This is code CSS:

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 770px)
{
    #contact-info
{
width:268px;
height:270px;
background:url(images/BODY-CONTACT.png);
position:relative;
margin:30px auto;
height:220px;
}
}
```

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">


 <!-- PLACE THIS LINE ABOVE YOUR HEADER -->


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="font-size:17px;">
      <img src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/DESPRE-NOI.png" class="img-responsive center-block" style="cursor:pointer;">
    </div>

  </div>



  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background:url(http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/themes/WordPressBootstrap-master/images/BODY-DROP.png);font-size:17px;/*display:none;*/">

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">


      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="color:white;;">


      </div>

      </div>


</div>


    <div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="color:white;;">
      <p>Cabinetul nostru a fost înfiinţat în anul 1997 de către Zorica L. Codoban, după o experienţă de 19 ani în domeniul juridic.
<br><br>
Activitatea cabinetului s-a concentrat de la început pe domeniul dreptului civil şi comercial. Competenţele cabinetului s-au extins în domeniul revendicărilor în temeiul legilor fondului funciar, iar după anul 2002 am început să asistăm clienţi în recuperarea imobilelor naţionalizate. Dreptul familiei, dreptul succesoral, dreptul muncii, legea insolvenţei au făcut parte constant din activitatea noastră. </p>
      <p> Am reprezentat instituţii publice, completând competenţele noastre în domeniul dreptului administrativ, achiziţiilor publice şi dreptului fiscal.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1" style="color:white;">
      <p> Anul 2010 a marcat momentul în care am ne-am implicat direct în activitatea clienţilor societăţi comerciale, asigurând deopotrivă reprezentarea acestora în instanţă şi asistenţa juridică în activităţile curente.<br><br> Pentru a ne atinge obiectivele impreuna cu clientii nostri am colaborat cu specialisti in proprietate intelectuala, fiscalitate, contabilitate. 

Ne caracterizează experienţa în domeniul juridic, însoţită de onestitatea şi eficienţa în raport cu interesele clienţilo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add padding-top or margin-top but unfortunately does not work.
Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: The problem with your page is the "footer" called header (which btw doesnt make much sence, but nvm) is fixed and blocks the view of everything, try working that around with simple rows and cols an you'll be fine. Edit: You're working too much with absolute positioning, try it with floating e.g. `float: right;`

Comment: and there is another version? I understand I have to change mutli stuff here.
You can Areti I on my code about what I should do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

delete this:

```
.navbar-default{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 12px;
}

#contact-info{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

add this: above xs:

```
#contact-info{
    float: right;
}
```